# xamarin forms ToolbarItem custom renderer

Tags: xamarin.forms, toolbar, toolbaritems

I want my ToolbarItems to have Color, HorizontalOptions and IsVisiblle properties, I know I should write a custom renderer, but as I'm new to xamarin I don't know which class I should derive my renderers from on each platform(iOS and Android) , is this even possible? I'd better say I want an extended toolbarItem.
Can anybody help please?